# Menu enumeration functions in X11?

Tags: firefox-addon, x11, jsctypes

I'm converting this test for screensaver stuff from linux code to js-ctypes.

It uses X11 heavily but I can't find any menu functions.

This is the code I'm trying convert:

```
1012     XMenuList::GetInstance()->InsertMenuWindowXIDs(&windows);
1013     // Enumerate the menus first.
1014     for (iter = windows.begin(); iter != windows.end(); iter++) {
1015       if (delegate->ShouldStopIterating(*iter))
1016         return true;
1017     }
1018     windows.clear();
```

this code is found here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/ui/base/x/x11_util.cc#1012

Basically im trying to enumerate through windows but they check for menus too when looking for screensaver.

I came across this note:

> X11, by itself, doesn't do menus. That is why toolkits like GTK, Qt, Motif, etc were created.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/x11-menus-how-to-839904/

Does this mean I should `ctypes.open` another library other then X11, does anyone know which one? I can't find.

Thanks

This is my code in progress: https://github.com/Noitidart/_scratchpad/blob/master/ScreensaverWindowExists.js#L365

This is the freedocs page im using for x11 functions: http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/manindex3.html

Comment: It's not clear what kind of menus do you mean. X11 has no notion of menu, as the note you are quoting rightly says. A toolkit can help *your program* implement menus, it does not not introduce menus to the X server, nor it can help you detect menus implemented by other programs. What does it mean to "enumerate menus in X11"?

Comment: OK if you look [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/ui/base/x/x11_menu_list.h#39) you can see that a menu, for Mozilla, is just a window that has `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` property set to `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_MENU`. It's a menu "torn off" the main application and pinned to the desktop. You don't need any special library to detect this, just use normal property manipulation functions. I don't quite understand why a screensaver would need that though.

Comment: Thank you @n.m. !! others if you know why google chrome does the code above "enum menus 1st" plz let me know :)

Comment: @n.m. can you please move your comments to solution if it wasn't for you i would have been lost till now i seriously appreciate your comments even though you arent jsctypes guy. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/chromium/source/src/ui/base/x/x11_menu_list.h#39), you can see that a menu, for Mozilla, is just a window that has `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE` property set to `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_MENU`.

The desktop standard says such windows are menus that are "torn off" their main application window and pinned to the desktop. You don't need any special library to detect this, just use normal property manipulation functions.

I don't quite understand why a screensaver would need that though.